# C++/sdl2 don't compile

Tags: c++, mingw, sdl-2

i was tring to do some c++/sdl2 dev, i looked through tutorials, put the SDL2.dll aside my file and used the command "g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -ISDL2\include -LSDL2\lib -Wall -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2", btw i used mingw for complier.
and i got this error:

C:\Users\tonys\AppData\Local\Temp\ccKD5qRR.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `SDL_Init' C:\Users\tonys\AppData\Local\Temp\ccKD5qRR.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x43): undefined reference to` SDL_CreateWindow'
C:\Users\tonys\AppData\Local\Temp\ccKD5qRR.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x51): undefined reference to `SDL_GetError' C:\Users\tonys\AppData\Local\Temp\ccKD5qRR.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x85): undefined reference to` SDL_PollEvent'
C:\Users\tonys\AppData\Local\Temp\ccKD5qRR.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xa6): undefined reference to `SDL_DestroyWindow' C:\Users\tonys\AppData\Local\Temp\ccKD5qRR.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xab): undefined reference to` SDL_Quit'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

i looked into more tutorials and they all explained the same thing i learn, so i'm kind of stuck.

Comment: `c:/mingw/bin/` I see you make your life hard. Use MSYS2 and its package manage pacman.

Comment: 1. Don't use such an old version of MinGW.  Instead install msys2 that has MinGW with gcc-13.2 instead of 6.3. 2. Use pacman to install sdl2.

Comment: When `-l...` mysteriously doesn't fix undefined references, it means that you're using x32 libs with an x64 compiler, or vice versa. But I second the advice to use MSYS2.